# SAP Web IDE does not recognize ES6

Tags: sap-web-ide

I want to write the code in ES6 on SAP Web IDE and follow the instruction https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/01/next-generation-javascript-in-ui5-using-sap-web-ide/.
[image]

But as you can see, I still get the error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62476313/5846045

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Right Click on the project folder
- Find and click on **Project Settings**
- Select JavaScript under "Code Checking"
- Select either Basic or Flori JavaScript
- Add **"es6" : true,** to "env":{} as shown here

```js
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true,
  "es6": true, /*<<<<<*/
  "amd": true,
  "mocha": true,
  "jquery": true
}
```

- Save and Close, error checking in your projects should be updated.

Comment: While this is a general suggestion to enable ES6 in ESlint, this doesn't seem to solve the problem the question author has. His [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMF7g.png) already contains `es6: true`.