# SAP Web IDE shows errors about ES6+ features

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5, eslint, sap-web-ide

```js
for (var items in _selectedContexts) {
  var downloadModel = __parsed[__parsed[items].toString().split("/")[1]][__parsed[items].toString().split("/")[2]];
  var length = downloadModel["Value"].length;
  var base64 = downloadModel["Value"];
  var bytes =  new Uint8Array(length);
  while (length--) {
    bytes[length] = base64.charCodeAt(length);
  }
  MessageToast.show(bytes.length);
}
```

How can I initialize a `Uint8Array` in UI5? I always get "Uint8Array is not defined" in SAP Web IDE as an error message. Do I need to import any special libraries?
I'm also using the latest SAPUI5 version and Chrome for testing so it shouldn't be a problem I guess?

Comment: Where (in which environment) will the script be executed that you are editing in web ide? What build tool chain is there?

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to figure it out for me. It's designed to be Fiori app therefore it will be launched over the Fiori launchpad. I hope this is the information you where looking for.

Comment: I don't know Web IDE and couldn't find anything on the web about it. The error message sounds very much like a linter or typechecker warning, and there should be a configuration file for this somewhere that would let you choose ES6 as the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore the message as long as your target browser supports the object. [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) was added to a somewhat newer JS specification (*ECMAScript 2015* aka. *ES6*). In order to make SAP Web IDE understand and parse ES6, **[add `es6`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) to the ESLint environment settings**:

1. Go to Project settings *>* Code Checking *>* JavaScript
2. Expand the *Validator Configuration* panel
3. Add `"es6": true` to the `env` object:

   ```json
   "env": {
     "es6": true,
     "...": "..."
   }
   ```

   This will edit the internal `.eslintrc` file accordingly.
4. <kbd>Save</kbd> the settings.